# gem push error - (Gem::Package::FormatError) - No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: rubygems

I tried to push a ruby gem for the first time while on a terrible internet connection. When I first tried to push, I was able to sign in and then it hung there for probably about 10 minutes with no sign of progress so I decided to just kill it and hit `ctrl+c`, which may have been a poor decision. From the session:

```
$ gem push test_config-0.1.0.gem
Enter your RubyGems.org credentials.
Don't have an account yet? Create one at https://rubygems.org/sign_up
   Email:   myemail@here.com
Password:   

Signed in.
^CERROR:  Interrupted
```

Now, when I try to push it again (on a better internet connection) I get the following:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Package::FormatError)
    No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - test_config-0.1.0.gem
    /Users/Scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:512:in `rescue in verify'
    /Users/Scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:490:in `verify'
    /Users/Scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:474:in `spec'
    /Users/Scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/push_command.rb:81:in `send_gem'
    /Users/Scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/push_command.rb:47:in `execute'
    /Users/Scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command.rb:305:in `invoke_with_build_args'
    /Users/Scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:167:in `process_args'
    /Users/Scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:137:in `run'
    /Users/Scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:54:in `run'
    /Users/Scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

I tried bumping the version and pushing that and I still get the same error.

Does anyone know how to go about resolving this error? Is it related to the fact that I killed the first attempt to push?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nevermind, I am an idiot. I didn't build the gem first, so of course there was no "test_config-0.1.0.gem" file to open. I built the gem first and now it works:

```
gem build test_config
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Just to clarify for anyone else who reads this, by _building_  @saclark means type `gem build test_config-0.1.0.gem` into the command line.

Comment: @SagarPandya just `gem build test_config` is fine. It will look for the version info in the gemspec file.