# Ruby Gem push not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I try a `gem push [gemname].gem, I get this error: 
(Gem::Package::FormatError) 
    No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

I have been trying to fix this for a day now and have been unable to figure it out. Anyone know how to fix this?

I have already tried this solution: [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749225/gem-push-error-gempackageformaterror-no-such-file-or-directory-rb-sy)

I have run gem build successfully, 
Still this error is occurring.

Comment: have you run `gem build`? Do you have `[gemname].gem` in your current directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749225/gem-push-error-gempackageformaterror-no-such-file-or-directory-rb-sy

Comment: I have run gem build , Im running 'gem push'  from the gem directory. Still having the same error.

Comment: I finally found a solution. Sorry it was my mistake , I am new to build gem . I didnot include version with gem name while pushing. Thanks all.